# Waiting room with only nearby players - Google Play Services

Tags: google-api, google-play, google-play-services, google-nearby

I am developing an Android multiplayer game and i would like to allow only nearby players to start a match. In order to do so I would like to create a room in which only nearby players are allowed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

[Play Games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer) has a gaming-specific API, that lets you launch a "Waiting Room" activity with the option to find nearby players (as well as friends online).

If you'd like the UI flow to be fully within your control, and to only support nearby players, then [Nearby Connections](https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/overview) is a lower level API that can do that.

I work on Nearby Connections, so I can give a quick overview of how to use it (sorry Play Games API). When the host creates a room, it should call [startAdvertising(serviceId=your.package.name, endpointName=roomName, strategy=P2P_STAR)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/Connections.html#startAdvertising(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.ConnectionLifecycleCallback,%20com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.AdvertisingOptions)) to broadcast the room's information to everyone nearby. Everyone in the waiting room should call [startDiscovery(serviceId=your.package.name, strategy=P2P_STAR)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/Connections.html#startDiscovery(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20java.lang.String,%20com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.EndpointDiscoveryCallback,%20com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.DiscoveryOptions)) to listen for advertisements. When those in the waiting room connect to the advertiser, they've "joined the game". It's up to you to decide how many players can connect before the game begins.

**Note:** Discovers can only talk to the advertiser, so keeping everyone in sync will require the advertiser to forward messages.

Comment: Let's not answer off-topic questions where OP has shown no effort whatsoever.